# Jquery function for hiding/unhiding div isn't working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio

I have two forms. `signin/signup` and `hospital/doctor` finder. Both are flat UI forms

The first form contains 3 links

- signin
- signup
- reset password

The problem is when I click on one of the aforementioned links, the hospital/doctor finder form, which is listed below, gets blank and vice versa.

Here's the jquery function for hiding/unhiding divs inside the form. The function is unambiguous but I'm unable to figure out why it's not working.

```
$(function () {
    // constants
    var SHOW_CLASS = 'show',
        HIDE_CLASS = 'hide',
        ACTIVE_CLASS = 'active';

    $('#tabs1').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tab = $(this),
             href = $tab.attr('href');

        $('.active').removeClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);
        $tab.addClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);

        $('.show')
           .removeClass(SHOW_CLASS)
           .addClass(HIDE_CLASS)
           .hide();

        $(href)
          .removeClass(HIDE_CLASS)
          .addClass(SHOW_CLASS)
          .hide()
        .fadeIn(550);
    });
});

$(function () {
    // constants
    var SHOW_CLASS = 'show',
        HIDE_CLASS = 'hide',
        ACTIVE_CLASS = 'active';

    $('#tabs2').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $tab = $(this),
             href = $tab.attr('href');

        $('.active').removeClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);
        $tab.addClass(ACTIVE_CLASS);

        $('.show')
           .removeClass(SHOW_CLASS)
           .addClass(HIDE_CLASS)
           .hide();

        $(href)
          .removeClass(HIDE_CLASS)
          .addClass(SHOW_CLASS)
          .hide()
        .fadeIn(550);
    });
});
```

Comment: can you also provide your html and css?

Comment: @Caner
i copied html and css from this link:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/flat-ui-login-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `$('.active')` and `$('.show')` you access **every instance** of them regardless of what "tab" they are on.  Without seeing the HTML I can't be sure but you can probably filter to the specific "tab" like so:

```
 $tab.find('.show')
       .removeClass(SHOW_CLASS)
       .addClass(HIDE_CLASS)
       .hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are tarrgetting all active class, youll have to use `this`
, or be more specific with the way you are selecting your class